# Exclude Specific Line By Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Wanna exclude the specific line "//2" from choose item.
<%-- //1 --%>

```
<%-- //1
//1 --%>

<%-- //1
//1
//1 --%>

//2

<%-- //1 --%>

<%-- //1 //1 --%>

//3
```

By JavaScript, Here is the regex: `(?<=<%-{2}[\w\W]*?)\/\/(?=[\w\W]*?-{2}%>)`

I found many ways but didn't work out. Could somebody have a good idea to fix it?

Comment: Here to check regex: https://regex101.com/r/qD5Yzc/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the opening `<%--` and then match until you encounter `//` without matching either `<%--` or `--%>`

Then do the same after matching `//` again.

In Javascript, instead of using `[\w\W]` you can also use `[^]`.

```
(?<=<%--(?:(?!<%--|--%>)[^])*)\/\/(?=(?:(?!<%--|--%>)[^])*--%>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYz6MT/1)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt. How's python regex look like?

Comment: @Arno If you want to use the quantifier `*` in the positive lookbehind, you could use the regex [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of `re`.  See this [code example](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourILGkJLUoT8FWoUhJw97G1kZVV1fD3krDXhHEqtHVVbXT1NPU0ozRj9HXsLfFIgWmlbhKUotL4otLioAmaSiBFCjo6xsqgCRj8mLylLgUkABcHkOCTD2kmKOvb4THdEK2K@A12VhJExikRZl5JRrg8NVLy8xLSczJ0YAGs44CLJh0IBGg5@If4ujjo6n5/z8A)